# Ionic 5 iOS app restarts when too many images are loaded

Tags: ios, image, ionic-framework, crash, restart

I hope you all having a great day.

Here is the deal, whenever I load a lot of products from API that has one image each one of the products, the app kind of does a restart, and it loads from the beginning.

In the beginning it was with simple `<img>` tag, I changed it to `ion-img`, and I saw that there was a big difference using the `ion-img` tag because it lazy loads the images.

But still, when I have loaded more that 40-60 products, and those images are loaded, the app still refreshes.

I remove the images, no images are shown, and the app works fine, but the app needs those images.

What might be the issue here? Am I missing something?

[Click Here for Streamable 1 video](https://streamable.com/yssza9)

Here the client wants to see product categories with a lot products in it

[Click here for Streamable 2 video.](https://streamable.com/okbo1p)

Here the client wants to select a product, but when it does, the app restarts.

The second video, is where I have tried, to remove the top 15 products, when get the next 15 on infinite scroll, but a scrolling flick happens because of that.

Here it is Ionic Info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.3 (/Users/leotrinelmazi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : ios 6.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 11 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.2) : 0.15.1
   native-run (update available: 1.3.0)   : 1.2.1

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.11.3
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v12.19.0 (/Users/leotrinelmazi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.8
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 12.3 Build version 12C33
```

here is a short code of the HTML that I am using to show the products and images.

```
<ion-grid style="margin: 10px;" class="ion-no-padding" *ngIf="data.length < 1">

        <div *ngFor="let sub of allData">

            <ion-row *ngIf="sub.products && sub.products.length > 0">

                <ion-col size="12">

                    <ion-item lines="none">

                        <div slot="start" style="text-transform: uppercase;

                        font-weight: bold;

                        font-size: 25px;">{{sub.title}}</div>

                         <ion-button slot="end" (click)="goToShowAll()"size="small" fill="outline" class="seeAllButtonClass"><span style="margin: 10px;">voir tout</span></ion-button>

                    </ion-item>

                </ion-col>

                <ion-col size-xs="6" *ngFor="let prods of sub.products">

                    <div class="products-scroll">

                        <div>

                            <ion-card (click)="goToDetail(prods)">

                                <ion-img class="img" src="{{prods.image}}" alt=""></ion-img>

                                <div class="diviParagrafit">

                                    <p>

                                        {{prods.price}}<small>{{this.webService.config.currency}}</small>

                                    </p>

                                    <p>

                                        {{prods.title}}

                                    </p>

                                </div>

                            </ion-card>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </ion-col>

            </ion-row>

        </div>

    </ion-grid>
```

This is the error I am getting on XCODE when the crash/restart happens:

```
2021-01-27 10:46:23.249648+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] [ProcessSuspension] 0x104aa9600 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process because PID is invalid

2021-01-27 10:46:23.250462+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] [Process] 0x10d02b418 - [pageProxyID=6, webPageID=7, PID=5068] WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 5068), reason 3

2021-01-27 10:46:23.258873+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}>

2021-01-27 10:46:23.258990+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] [ProcessSuspension] 0x104aa9640 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 5068, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}

2021-01-27 10:46:23.270927+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] [Loading] 0x10d02b418 - [pageProxyID=6, webPageID=7, PID=5068] WebPageProxy::dispatchProcessDidTerminate: reason = 3

2021-01-27 10:46:24.568454+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] {"id":1,"admin_id":1,"company_name":"Moda Pas Cher","logo":"https://modapascher.com/storage/images/1/logo/logo.png","admin_theme":"blush","about_desc":null,"address":"France","main_email":"info@modapascher.com","tel":null,"hotline_support":1,"hotline_num":"075976979,3599785748,486845648","shipping_fee":"8.00","min_o_free":"0.00","processing_fee":"0.00","currency":"€","cash_payment":0,"shipping_type":1,"privacy_policy":null,"terms_condition":null,"status":1,"facebook":"https://www.facebook.com/ModaPasCherFR/videos/?ref=page_internal","twitter":null,"instagram":"https://www.instagram.com/modapascher/","created_at":"2020-08-31T06:54:23.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-26T13:51:15.000000Z"}

2021-01-27 10:46:24.568628+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 385 ms

2021-01-27 10:46:24.569162+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] initializing

2021-01-27 10:46:24.572560+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] OPEN database: _ionicstorage

2021-01-27 10:46:24.572763+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] new transaction is queued, waiting for open operation to finish

2021-01-27 10:46:24.572905+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3810022] -[SQLitePlugin closeNow:] [Line 237] close db name: _ionicstorage

2021-01-27 10:46:24.609135+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3810287] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 87 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 87 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}

2021-01-27 10:46:24.634035+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3810022] -[SQLitePlugin openNow:] [Line 176] open full db path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2C4C0F50-3329-4F3D-8623-5666F98DC108/Library/LocalDatabase/_ionicstorage

2021-01-27 10:46:24.645036+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] OPEN database: _ionicstorage - OK

2021-01-27 10:46:24.645193+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] DB opened: _ionicstorage

2021-01-27 10:46:24.698638+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] The preference key "AutoHideSplashScreen" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"

2021-01-27 10:46:24.780668+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3810022] Request <OSRequestRegisterUser: 0x283d8be70> success result {

    id = "0008ce03-34fc-474c-bb1b-a1b211524dec";

    success = 1;

}

2021-01-27 10:46:53.251675+0100 ModaPasCher[4808:3587108] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the HTML TAG `<ion-card>`.

After I removed that tag, and replaced it with `<ion-grid>` everything was working fine on iOS.

But, thanks for letting me know about `ion-virtual-scroll` @E. maginni , I will give it a try and use it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you try to run it in the browser? Same result?

Chances are you need to use [ion-virtual-scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/virtual-scroll#ios-cordova-wkwebview) to handle the memory management. In particular, note the documentation regarding iOS and wkWebView.

Comment: Hello, Browser and Android are fine, iOS was not working properly. 

Thank you for letting me know about ion-virtual-scroll, I am going to give it a try.

The issue was the HTML TAG - <ion-card>.
After I removed that and replaced it with ion-grid, the issue was gone on iOS.

Thanks alot.